# Проблема с блоками + подвалом

Tags: html, css

Вот ставлю я черный блок на весь `widht: 100%`, а html блокирует и слево  создает невидимый барьер? Так же с верхним подвалом (картинка 2), вроде widht а вроде и проблему не решает. Что делать?
[image: блок]

[image: подвал]

Вот подвал: (В html только одна кнопка, без нее проблема имеется, поэтому html ставить не вижу смысла

```
.top {
    background: black;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Вот блок:

```
.block1 {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 40%;
}
```

html смысла нету добавлять - я удалил в body все кроме блока а проблема оталась.
Вообщем заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: А вы  обнулили все стили браузера?*

Comment: У меня во всех такая проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* Указываем box sizing*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Убираем внутренние отступы */
ul[class],
ol[class] {
  padding: 0;
}

/* Убираем внешние отступы */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ul[class],
ol[class],
li,
figure,
figcaption,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Выставляем основные настройки по-умолчанию для body */
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/* Удаляем стандартную стилизацию для всех ul и il, у которых есть атрибут class*/
ul[class],
ol[class] {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Элементы a, у которых нет класса, сбрасываем до дефолтных стилей */
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

/* Упрощаем работу с изображениями */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Указываем понятную периодичность в потоке данных у article*/
article > * + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

/* Наследуем шрифты для инпутов и кнопок */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/* Удаляем все анимации и переходы для людей, которые предпочитай их не использовать */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  * {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}
```

[ТУТ](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B8%CC%86-%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-css-f5816963c82b)

Comment: Если ты такой гений давай вместе делать сайт?)

Comment: Ты и без меня справишься с гуглом :) удачи в начинаниях.

Comment: Я знаю, но у меня таких статей нету, а то сообщение было шуткой

Comment: эх, а я почти согласился ><

Comment: согласился? судя по сообщению нет